# How to align a button bottom with multiline edit text in linear layout Android

Tags: android, xml

I'd like to align a `Button` and a multiLine `EditText` at the bottom of the screen. They should both be beside each other. Both of these are currently in a `LinearLayout`. How do I do this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To:"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/To"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.86"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Browse"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout" />

<!-- 
            <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/awain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout" 
            android:text="Listview"

            /> -->




    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


        >
           <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"

                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="2000"
                android:maxLines="5"  />

      <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Send"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            </Button>





      </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>













</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't take it as an offence please, but first you need to rephrase your request because your English is so bad that we simply cannot understand what you want. :)

Comment: It always helps if you share whatever code you have so far so that people who're helping you have a starting point.

Comment: how can i show my xml code here?  Please do let me know i am new here

Comment: @user2552435 : Edit your question and paste your xml file inside the answer box then select the xml part and press clt+k and it will be added.

Comment: In xml you can see there is a EditText (Multiline)..When user enters text in edit text and it grows so as it grows the Send Button also moves towards top.. But it should not move towards top and it should stay on its place..Please help me regarding ths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the relative layout as parent of your Linerlayout

See the example here..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your edit text"
        android:maxLines="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: copy your xml file code and click on edit link below your question link and then paste the xml code below your question. You have to give blank space four times from the start of line in your xml code.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:lines="3"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="test"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is xml file only. Use it in your activity.

Comment: Let me tell you what the problem exactly is..In xml you can see there is a EditText (Multiline)..When user enters text in edit text and it grows so as it grows the Send Button also moves towards top.. But it should not move towards top and it should stay on its place

Answer (score 1):

@user2552435

You use RelativeLayout, change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```